# How to transcribe audio in Twilio and using Python?

Tags: python, twilio

Hi everyone Im in a tangle as how to recorded, transcribe and retrieve the text from the transcription in Twilio. How do I do it? Example:

```
# Download the Python helper library from twilio.com/docs/python/install
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "AC30bd8bdca7572344721eb96c15a5c0c7"
auth_token  = "your_auth_token"
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

transcription = client.transcriptions.get("TR8c61027b709ffb038236612dc5af8723")
print(transcription.transcription_text)
```

in client.transcriptions.get, How do I get the latest transcription? I need the Uri (I believe) but have no idea how to access it/variable name.

On a side note, what alternatives to the Twilio transcription are there and how do I access the appropriate recordings in my script to transcribe?

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/transcription

Comment: I need the transcription sid, but no idea of the variable name for it in python.

Comment: Another option would be to set the `RecordingUrl` and/or `TranscriptionUrl` parameters in the `<Record>` verb.  This lets Twilio tell you when a recording and transcription are are complete rather than you having to check.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can access all your transcriptions by listing them as follows:

```
# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
account_sid = "AC30bd8bdca7572344721eb96c15a5c0c7"
auth_token  = "your_auth_token"
client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

for transcription in client.transcriptions.list():
    print transcription.transcriptiontext
```

You can also set the `TranscriptionUrl` attribute so you get notified with a transcription ID when a transcription is complete. That way you can use the code snipped you posted above.